# iOS prevent subview of tableview from scrolling with tableview

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, tableview, subview

I have added a subview to my tableview and when ever the user scrolls the tableview, the subview scrolls with it. How do I prevent this? I know it's probably along the lines of not adding the view to the tableview's subviews, but I have no knowledge of any other ways to do this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? A table-view with a static background?

Comment: Add your view in question onto the parent of the tableview.

Comment: A standard tableview, scroll enabled. I have a "Connection Timeout" view that is a subview of the tableview that animates out to appear, and then hides again. If the user scrolls the table when the view is showing, it scrolls with the table...

Comment: Are you sure you are not talking about a `UITableViewController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a view a subview of the table view, then you can make it floating (non-scrolling) by changing its origin.y value in the scrollViewDidScroll method.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.iv.frame = CGRectMake(self.ivOrigin.x, self.ivOrigin.y + self.tableView.bounds.origin.y, self.iv.frame.size.width, self.iv.frame.size.height);
}
```

In this example, "iv" is a property for an image view, and "ivOrigin" is a property for the initial origin of the image view (defined when I created the image view and its frame in viewDidLoad).

Answer (score 2):

The UITableView is built and intended to be a view of things that scroll.

So, you can either fight that, which as you're discovering is quite hard since everything about the component is built and focused around scrolling and fast display of a subset of the full list data... Or, you can not fight it and put your static item on top of the table as a fixed-position item.

If there's a reason you can't add the table view and your animate-out item in your main view, you can always add a custom UIView class that contains both the table view and your animated view. Have your custom view class expose the contained table view as a .table property, and the container you're putting things in can be tweaked to use "mycontainerObject.tableview" instead of just "tableview" where needed.

Yes, it's a little more work to write the custom UIView subclass and give it a couple properties to hold the UITableView and whatever UIView you're animating out.. but it's likely a lot safer in the long run than trying to "hack" into the UITableView's methods and view hierarchy to try to give it a "fixed in place" behavior.